# how to fetch list of all pda accounts in frontend? like sale account instance to display in the market? or should i be fetching from token account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, account, anchor-client

i have a sale order account defined like this..

```
#[account]
pub struct Order {
    pub creator: Pubkey,
    pub mint_key: Pubkey,
    pub memo: String,
    pub price: u64,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

And this is the function to create nft sale order instance.

```
pub fn create_order(ctx: Context<CreateOrder>, memo: String, price: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let order = &mut ctx.accounts.order;
    order.creator = ctx.accounts.creator.key();
    order.mint_key = ctx.accounts.mint_key.key();
    order.memo = memo;
    order.price = price;
    order.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("order").unwrap();

    //
    // transfer nft from creator's token account into order's token account.
    //
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.creator_token_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.order_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.creator.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    let result = transfer(cpi_ctx, 1);
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::TokenTransferFailed));
    }

    return Ok(());
}
```

this is the context i am providing.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(memo: String)]
pub struct CreateOrder<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = creator,
        space = Order::space(&memo),
        seeds = [
            b"order",
            mint_key.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub order: Account<'info, Order>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = creator,
        associated_token::mint = mint_key,
        associated_token::authority = order
    )]
    pub order_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub mint_key: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut, 
        constraint=creator_token_account.owner == creator.key(),
        constraint=creator_token_account.mint == mint_key.key()
    )]
    pub creator_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

I want to display all the sale Order instance in the frontend market. How can I acheive this?
somebody pls take a look and tell me if I am doing something wrong or is there a way to do this..? thank you

Answer (score 3):

With PDAs, you can build a "*hashmap-like*" structure. but it's only hashmap-**like**. There is now way to iterate over all PDAs that were created.

There are a few options on how to mitigate this.

You can either keep track of which PDAs you created in a separate "bookkeeping" PDA that you update within your CreateOrder instruction. Then, in your client, you can just read the bookkeeping PDA and display the info you want to show.

You could also query the blockchain with transactions that were completed before, and try to build a list of PDAs that were created. You can use `getSignaturesForAddress` for your ProgramId, and the get and parse all transactions using `getTransactions` and `getParsedTransaction`. It's documented in the official @solana/web3.js docs, and you will be especially interested in the [getSignaturesForAddress page](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress).

The second route is tedious, takes a lot of time and resources, can hit the rate limit of your RPC node quite quickly, and it's not guaranteed how far back your RPC node stores transaction history. You can use GenesysGo as your RPC provider to overcome the latter restriction.

I strongly recommend the first approach over the second. However, if you already have some history of transactions that you don't have a bookkeeping PDA for, then it will be some effort to retroactively create that bookkeeping, e.g. using the second method.

Comment: Thank you, can u please point me to "bookkeeping" example which is used in similar use cases...?

Comment: @Lobo1897 have you found the answer? As far as I know we can't store an unlimited size `Vec<PubKey>` so I don't know what we can do to keep track of all the PDAs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch all the order accounts your anchor program has created, which will return all instances of the `Order` account type.

First, set up in the frontend something like the following using `"@project-serum/anchor"` and  `"@solana/wallet-adapter-react"`. You'll also need to import the `IDL` for your program.

```
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
  const { connection } = useConnection()

  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {})

  setProvider(provider)
  const program = new Program(IDL as Idl, programId)
```

then you can fetch all the order accounts like this

```
const allOrderAccounts = await program.account.order.all()
```

or apply a filter to fetch for a specific accounts. The example below fetches the `order` accounts where the `creator` field matches a specific `creator`. The 8 byte offset is to account for a discriminator that all accounts created in an anchor program generally have.

```
const filterOrderAccounts = await program.account.order.all([
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 8,
              bytes: creator.publicKey.toBase58(),
            },
          },
        ])
```

Comment: I am using "useWallet" for wallet... Should I change it to useAnchorWallet...??

Comment: And also how can I get the NFT data to display? The metadata ?

Comment: You have to use `useAnchorWallet` because the wallet object from `useWallet` is not directly compatible with Anchor. Assuming each `mint_key` is an NFT with a metadata account, to get the data to display you'll have to fetch the metadata account associated with each mint. Check out the Metaplex SDK which simplifies the process:  https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js

Comment: Thank you I will check that... One quick follow up... Is there also way to fetch only nfts minted by my contract?

Comment: Can I use "signTransaction"  (useAnchorWallet) In place of "sendTransaction" (useWallet)...??

Comment: You can test and see if it works, I've never used ```signTransaction``` with ```useAnchorWallet```. I generally still use ```sendTransaction``` from ```useWallet``` to prompt a connect wallet to sign a transaction and only use the wallet from ```useAnchorWallet``` to set up anchor. Also, not sure about your nft question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Solana JSON RPC API calling [getProgramAccounts](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts)

This will return all `accounts` owned by the provided program `pubkey`

In order to filter only to certain types of accounts.

e.g. Order Accounts (PDAs) specify the `data size` in the request. This will return only the `accounts` that have that `data size` (Order Pda Account)

**example**

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "4Nd1mBQtrMJVYVfKf2PJy9NZUZdTAsp7D4xWLs4gDB4T",
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 17
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

this will return all the `accounts` (PDAs or not) that have `17 bytes` of data allocated.